# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') while using map function in useEffect

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(currentUser){
            currentUser?.friends.map(friends => {
                if(friends._id===currentProfile._id){
                    return setFriend(true)
                }
            })
        }else{
            return setFriend(false)
        }
    },[currentUser,currentProfile])

//currentUser is the user logged in
//currentProfile is user selected
```

i want to show button as Unfriend if the user selected is already a friend.Iam trying to use a map function to find if the user is already a friend.but the map function is shown as error

Comment: Can you please show where you defined currentUser or from where you get currentUser data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like `currentUser` is defined but doesn't have a property `currrentUser.friends`.
Try `currentUser?.friends?.map(...)`

And change the `else` clause to always return instead. If `return setFriend(true)` was called, the `return friend(false)` won't be called, but in all other cases.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the if statement we already know that currentUser exists you will have to see if the currentUser have friends.
However map should be used to create a new array, you use it to iterate over friends. You could simplify the whole useEffect with `some` instead

```js
useEffect(() => {
  setFriend(
    currentUser &&
      currentUser.friends?.some((friends) => friends._id === currentProfile._id)
  );
}, [currentUser, currentProfile]);
```

If currentUser is a value and a friend have the same id as currentProfile